# I want to store Zk4500 fingerprint reader template in k50 biometric attendance machine both are from zktecho

Tags: java, python, fingerprint, biometrics, zkteco

I want to store Zk4500 fingerprint  template in k50  biometric  attendance machine . I am using java for zk4000 scanner and python for communicating with attendance machine(k 50).

```
public void onAccept(){
    if (count == 1){
        image1.setImage(imageView.getImage());

        fingerPrintTemplateForDB1 = FingerprintSensorEx.BlobToBase64(template, templateLen[0]);
        System.out.println(fingerPrintTemplateForDB1);

        ++count;
    }else
    if (count == 2){
        image2.setImage(imageView.getImage());
        fingerPrintTemplateForDB2 = FingerprintSensorEx.BlobToBase64(template, templateLen[0]);
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to store this template in
fingerPrintTemplateForDB1 = FingerprintSensorEx.BlobToBase64(template, templateLen[0]);

```
from zk import ZK, const
from zk.finger import Finger
conn = None
zk = ZK('192.168.10.201', port=4370, timeout=5, password=0, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
conn = zk.connect()
conn.disable_device()
conn.set_user(uid=6, name='ahmed f', privilege=const.USER_ADMIN, password='12345678', group_id='', user_id='6', card=0)

fingerPrintTemplateForDB1 = "Template from Zk45000"

Myfinger = {
    "uid": 6,
    "fid": 6,
    "valid": 1,
    'template': fingerPrintTemplateForDB1
}
users = conn.get_users()
for user in users:
    if user.user_id == "3":
         conn.save_user_template(user, [ Finger.json_unpack(Myfinger)])
```

I think the main issue is in Finger print object In python :

```
from struct import pack #, unpack
import codecs


class Finger(object):

    def __init__(self, uid, fid, valid, template):
        self.size = len(template) # template only
        self.uid = int(uid)
        self.fid = int(fid)
        self.valid = int(valid)
        self.template = template
        #self.mark = str().encode("hex")
        self.mark = codecs.encode(template[:8], 'hex') + b'...' + codecs.encode(template[-8:], 'hex')

    def repack(self): #full
        return pack("HHbb%is" % (self.size), self.size+6, self.uid, self.fid, self.valid, self.template)

    def repack_only(self): #only template
        return pack("H%is" % (self.size), self.size, self.template)

    @staticmethod
    def json_unpack(json):
        return Finger(
            uid=json['uid'],
            fid=json['fid'],
            valid=json['valid'],
            template=codecs.decode(json['template'],'hex')
        )

    def json_pack(self): #packs for json
        return {
            "size": self.size,
            "uid": self.uid,
            "fid": self.fid,
            "valid": self.valid,
            "template": codecs.encode(self.template, 'hex').decode('ascii')
        }

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Finger> [uid:{:>3}, fid:{}, size:{:>4} v:{} t:{}]".format(self.uid, self.fid, self.size, self.valid, self.mark)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Finger> [uid:{:>3}, fid:{}, size:{:>4} v:{} t:{}]".format(self.uid, self.fid, self.size, self.valid, self.mark)

    def dump(self):
        return "<Finger> [uid:{:>3}, fid:{}, size:{:>4} v:{} t:{}]".format(self.uid, self.fid, self.size, self.valid, codecs.encode(self.template, 'hex'))
```

But nothing is working Can anyone have an idea .

I am using this unofficial library

```
 pip install -U pyzk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution the main problem was k50 was using ZkFingerprint10.0 algorithm and zk4500 was using algorithm ZkFingerprint9.0 by  updating drivers of zk4500 from website https://www.zkteco.com/en/product_detail/ZKFinger-SDK-Windows.html
(not from CD) to latest version....problem was solved